# How to modify matched values regex in C#

Tags: c#, json, regex, replace

I am trying to parse some JSON i receive. The JSON i receive contain whitespaces and underscores which i want to get rid of.

```
{"No_":"SL00101","Description":"Logies_3","Description_2":"","Customer No_":"1234","Name":"SomeName"}
```

With the following regex i match the

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*\":)
```

I want to change the variables to not have any underscores or whitespaces.
So: 
No_ becomes No

And

Customer No_ becomes CustomerNo.

I've tried subsitution and replace, but i can't find how to modify the matched values.

For example

```
var newJason = Regex.Replace(json, "(?<variableName>([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*\":))", "${variableName}".Replace(" ", string.Empty));
```

Comment: Have you looked at `Regex.Replace` ?

Comment: You would be better using a a JSON parser, converting the results with the naming you want and serialising. That way you don't need to work out what is an identifier and what is a value. (As JSON is not a regular language – in the formal sense – regular expressions cannot be used to process it reliably.)

Comment: *Why* do you want to replace the underscore? Are you having trouble mapping this to your classes perhaps? You can specify alternate mappings through attributes, eg with [JsonProperty](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute__ctor_1.htm). You can even specify your own [naming strategy](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_NamingStrategy.htm) to take care of underscores. No need for replacements

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I want it to change the names so they match namingconventions without mapping it manually :)

Comment: Then you can write your own NamingStrategy

Comment: Or you can write your own [ContractResolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm) and set it in [the default settings](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DefaultSettings.htm). Replacement is **no** a viable option as it delays deserialization, generates temporary strings and puts pressure on the garbage collector

Answer (score 1):

SO you want to rename your json properties, probably because you want decent names in c#

rather add Newtonsoft.Json Library via NuGet and the set your property name with the JsonProperty Attribute.

```
public class YourClass
{
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "No_")]
   public string No{ get; set; }

   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Customer No_")]
   public string CustomerNo{ get; set; }
}
```

You can now deserialize to your c# class with Properties that is following naming convention.

Deserialize with

```
var yourClassInstance = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClass>("yourJsonString");
```

Answer (score -1):

This may help you:

```
var jsonString = "";
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
jsonString += "{";
for (var key in obj) {
    jsonString += '"' + key.replace("/_/g","").replace("/ /g","") + ":" + obj[key] + '",'
}
jsonString = jsonString.slice(0,-1)  //we remove the last comma (,)
jsonString += "}";                   //and we close the future json object
```

You could then add a `var resultJsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString)` to get the final json object